# handsontable - Refresh data and maintain filter and sort conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, handsontable

I use handsontable as the front end to a MySQL database sitting on a webserver. Users filter, sort, modify etc. the data on the front end handsontable.

Changes happen in the backend MySQL database for various reasons. And I need to sync this information back to the users front end.

I can easily do this using a HTTP request to re-download the data from the database and write this data to the handsontable using the following code snippet.

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "my-data-url",
    data: "my-post-data"
  }).then(function(response){
    // response contains the handsontable data
    var json_response = response.data;
    // Update the data in my table instance
    hot.updateSettings({
        data: json_response
    })
    // hot looses its sort and filter conditions...
    // how can I maintain these or re-apply them??
  });
```

The problem is this code clears all the users current sort and filter conditions. Where I would like to persist these when the handsontable data object is updated. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue. The solution to each aspect is as follows:

**Filters**

Updating the version of Handsontable to version v1.11.0 maintained the filters on its own when updating the data setting.

**Sorting**

Updating the above method as follows:

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: "my-data-url",
  data: "my-post-data"
}).then(function(response){
  // response contains the handsontable data
  var json_response = response.data;

  // Get sort data of handsontable prior to updating the data setting
  if (isSorted(hot) == true) {
      var sortData = getSortData(hot)
  } 

  // Update the data in my table instance
  hot.updateSettings({
      data: json_response
  })

  // Re-apply previous sorts
  if (sortData) {
      hot.sort(sortData.sortColumn, sortData.sortOrder);
  }

  });

// Determines if sorts have been applied
var isSorted = function (hot_instance) {
    return hot_instance.sortingEnabled && typeof hot_instance.sortColumn != 'undefined' && typeof hot_instance.sortOrder != 'undefined';
}

// gets the sort data for a handsontable passed
var getSortData = function (hot_instance) {
  var sortData = [];
  // Get sorted column number
  var columnNo = hot_instance.sortColumn;
  // Get current sort order of column
  // false = desceding order
  var sortOrder = hot_instance.sortOrder;
  sortData.sortColumn = columnNo;
  sortData.sortOrder = sortOrder;
  return sortData;
}
```

Hope that helps someone having a similar issue.